# Unable to build Meteor project remotely through a Java application

Tags: java, eclipse, ubuntu, meteor, processbuilder

I am trying to run Meteor project from Java application and this is the code I have written for it:

```
String[] command  = { "/bin/bash", "-c" ,"cd /home/cloud2/Music/MyMeteorProject; meteor run android-device" };
ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(command);
        builder.redirectErrorStream(true);
        Process process=null;
        try {
            process = builder.start();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        InputStream is = process.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

        String line = null;
        try {
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
               System.out.println(line);// This line display error message on the console
        } catch (IOException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Building Meteor project from Java application shows following error in Eclipse console:

> Your system does not yet seem to fulfill all requirements to build
>   apps for Android.
>
> Please follow the installation instructions in the mobile guide:
>   http://guide.meteor.com/mobile.html#installing-prerequisites
>
> Status of the individual requirements:
>
> ✓ Java JDK
>
> ✗ Android SDK:
>   Failed to find 'ANDROID_HOME' environment variable. Try setting
>   setting it manually.   Failed to find 'android' command in your
>   'PATH'. Try update your 'PATH' to   include path to valid SDK
>   directory.
>
> ✗ Android target: Android SDK not found. Make sure that it
>   is installed. If it   is not at the default location, set the
>   ANDROID_HOME environment variable.
>
> ✗ Gradle: Could not find gradle
>   wrapper within Android SDK. Could not find   Android SDK directory.
>   Might need to install Android SDK or set up 'ANDROID_HOME' env
>   variable.

But when I run the same project from the terminal it runs fine so it looks like ANDROID_HOME is already set. Then why does the project not run from the Java application?

Comment: Are you using Eclipse or anyother IDE to run the program?

Comment: I am using eclipse to run my java application.

Comment: Can't you import the project as Android project and run it from Eclipse?

Comment: It is not a Android project , it is a hybrid Meteor app. I am accessing the terminal from java application and then building the meteor project from there.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, adding the ANDROID_HOME as below.

```
 try {
      Map<String, String> envs = pb.environment();
      System.out.println(envs.get("Path"));
      envs.put("ANDROID_HOME", "<ANDROID_PATH>");
      pb.redirectErrorStream();
      process = builder.start();
   } catch (IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
   }
```

Comment: I added sdk path-> System.setProperty("ANDROID_HOME", "/home/cloud2/Android/Sdk");  like you said but it also does not work.

Comment: Is ANDROID_HOME is in the env path? If not add it and also add android-sdk/tools folder to the env path and give it a try.

Comment: It is set too. The .bashrc file contains it.

Comment: export ANDROID_HOME=/home/cloud2/Android/Sdk

export PATH=$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$PATH
export PATH=$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools:$PATH

Comment: Can you check if the program is getting those env values by doing the below? Add these lines before the ProcessBuilder call.  Map<String,String> paths = System.getenv(); System.out.println(paths);

Comment: The ev are rightly said and it wont be any problem if meteor project is built from terminal but it somehow doesn't get ANDROID_HOME from java application.